# Python window issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a software where you can add textboxes, move them around and then save it. But somehow for me the save function is not working properly.

When I load the file, the "Add" button is somehow missing from the toolbar, the textbox and inputs are not saved in position. Also somehow I'm not able to move the textbox anymore.

Any help is very much appreciated it :)

```
`import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

text_boxes = []  # List to store position and text input for each text box

def save_file():
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".leaff", filetypes=[("Leaf Files", "*.leaff")])
    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, "w") as file:
            for text_box in text_boxes:
                x = text_box["frame"].winfo_x()
                y = text_box["frame"].winfo_y()
                text = text_box["text"]
                file.write(f"{x},{y},{text}\n")
        new_window.wm_title(file_path)

def save_as_file():
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Leaf Files", "*.leaff")])
    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, "w") as file:
            for text_box in text_boxes:
                x = text_box["frame"].winfo_x()
                y = text_box["frame"].winfo_y()
                text = text_box["text"]
                file.write(f"{x},{y},{text}\n")
        new_window.wm_title(file_path)



def load_new_branch():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Leaf Files", "*.leaff")])
    if file_path:
        for text_box in text_boxes:
            text_box["frame"].destroy()
        text_boxes.clear()
        with open(file_path, "r") as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                line = line.strip()
                if line:
                    try:
                        x, y, text = line.split(",")
                        frame = tk.Frame(new_window, bd=0)
                        frame.grid(row=int(y), column=int(x), padx=2, pady=2)
                        text_entry = tk.Entry(frame, bd=0)
                        text_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
                        text_entry.insert(tk.END, text)
                        text_boxes.append({"frame": frame, "x": int(x), "y": int(y), "text": text})
                    except ValueError:
                        print(f"Invalid line format: {line}")
                        continue
                else:
                    print("Empty line found in file")




def create_new_branch():
    window.withdraw()

    global new_window
    new_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    new_window.geometry("700x400")
    new_window.title("New Branch")  # Set initial window title to "New Branch"

    def add_text():
        frame = tk.Frame(new_window, bd=0)
        frame.pack(pady=2)

        text_entry = tk.Entry(frame, bd=0)
        text_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        def start_drag(event):
            event.x = frame.winfo_rootx()
            event.y = frame.winfo_rooty()

        def drag(event):
            x = min(max(frame.winfo_x() + event.x, 0),
                    new_window.winfo_width() - frame.winfo_width())
            y = min(max(frame.winfo_y() + event.y, 0),
                    new_window.winfo_height() - frame.winfo_height())
            frame.place(x=x, y=y)

        text_entry.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", start_drag)
        text_entry.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)

        text_boxes.append({"frame": frame, "x": 0, "y": 0, "text": text_entry.get()})

    def add_image():
        print("Image added")

    def return_to_main_menu():
        new_window.destroy()
        window.deiconify()

    file_menu = tk.Menu(new_window)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_file)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Save As", command=save_as_file)
    file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=return_to_main_menu)

    add_menu = tk.Menu(new_window)
    add_menu.add_command(label="Text", command=add_text)
    add_menu.add_command(label="Image", command=add_image)

    menu_bar = tk.Menu(new_window)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
    menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Add", menu=add_menu)
    new_window.config(menu=menu_bar)

    new_window.mainloop()

window = tk.Toplevel(root)
window.geometry("700x400")
window.title("Leaf")

original_image = Image.open("images/Leaf.jpg")
resized_image = original_image.resize((700, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)

background_label = tk.Label(window, image=background_image)
background_label.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

button_width = 20

create_button = tk.Button(window, text="Create new branch", command=create_new_branch, width=button_width)
create_button.place(relx=0.64, rely=0.375)

load_button = tk.Button(window, text="Load new branch", command=load_new_branch, width=button_width)
load_button.place(relx=0.64, rely=0.475)

window.mainloop()`
```

I tried moving the code around, but it seems to still cause issues.

Comment: Please explain in detail what you mean by the code 'causes issues."  Provide a user scenario, explain what results versus what you want to result.

Comment: The software I'm trying to make is like Scapple. You can create a new document, add text and pictures and be able to move them around by clicking and dragging.  The issue is the saving feature. It doesn't save properly. When I load the a file it shows the textbox I added, but not the position i left it in last and also the box is empty instead of having the text I wrote in it. So it won't save properly. On top of that when you create a new document it says "ADD" on the toolbar up top, but when I load a document the "ADD" isn't there in the toolbar.

Comment: While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.